# Eliminate the duplicates from the array in powershell script

Tags: powershell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEYSj.png)I imported a CSV which has two groups and group members displayed before them. there are duplicate members in both the groups like :
Group A:

John Harry Berke

1. John
2. Tom
3. Hilton

Group B:

1. John
2. Louise

(John is repeated),
So I did the below code to add all the group members in a array and then print the unique from them but it does not works.The array has repeated names

```
    $Global:grpmember = @()
    $CSV=Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\LicenseCount\Names.csv" -delimiter ","
    $csv | % {
    $grpmember+= $_.GroupMembers
    Write-Host "I am executed"
    }
    $grpmember | Get-Unique -AsString
```

enter image description here

Comment: Your question doesn't compute as **`.CSV` files do not support line breaks** (as you can see from your paste: all names are joined with a single space) and I am sure that if you import this `.CSV` back into your application (or Excel) you will find that that all the names are joined with a single space. How do you want separate the names if you can't make a difference between the space first/last name and each full name? I think that you need to forget about `.CVS` files and fallback on e.g. the [`PSExcel`](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PSExcel-Intro/) module.

Comment: Any work around ? I have to combine the members of two groups(part of 1 application)  and then extract unique members from them to count the licenses.... because of repeating names of the same user in different groups , the count is also duplicating for the license

Comment: That depends whether the source application(where the screenshot comes from) can export to something else then CSV files or can e.g. escape newlines with something like ``... `r`n...`` or `...\r\n...`

Answer (score 8):

[Get-Unique](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113335) should work here. But it needs a sorted array, and your input is not sorted.

There are some other options. Suppose you have an array, say:

```
$array = @('a', 'b', 'c', 'a')
```

You can use `select -uniq` or `sort -uniq` in this case, to remove duplicates from the above array.

```
$array= $array | select -uniq
# or
$array= $array | sort -uniq
```

Comment: $Global:grpmember = @()
$CSV=Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\LicenseCount\Names.csv" -delimiter "," | Sort -Unique

 $csv | % {
    
    
    $grpmember+= $_.GroupMembers
 
   Write-Host "I am executed"
}
  $grpmember|Get-Unique -AsString

Comment: This only runs for 1 group and ignores other groups in the csv

Comment: is your csv malformed ? What about case sensitivity ?

Comment: Can you paste the csv file in the question ? I didn't understand the structure of the csv.

Comment: I have the 'Application name' , 'Group Name', 'Group Users' as heading.The The application name is same, but there are 2 groups - A01 admin,A01 users. Then the group members are displayed before them

Comment: #TYPE System.Object
GroupName,"GroupMembers","GroupId","AppName","GroupLicenses","TotalUserCount","LicensedUserCount","LicenseErrorCount"
A02_users,"John DOE
Bob Sponge
app team
Patrick Star
Coordinator
Data Owner1
Data Owner2
Data Owner3
Data Owner4
Data Owner5
Data Owner6
Data Owner7
Data Owner8
Data Owner9
Data Owner10
Data Owner11
Badr Nhairy","d1360ff1-6358-4ad7-aa7d-37bb2ea6c36c","AIFMD02",,"17","5","0"
AIFMD02_admin,"John DOE
app team
Neha Srivastava","6a29b8b2-dfcf-4c13-a7ca-5675c73d5823","AIFMD02",,"3","2","0"

Comment: if you paste this in your csv file and remove the delimeter you see the csv data

Comment: this is the result:  John DOE
Bob Sponge
app team
Patrick Star
Coordinator
Data Owner1
Data Owner2
Data Owner3
Data Owner4
Data Owner5
Data Owner6
Data Owner7
Data Owner8
Data Owner9
Data Owner10
Data Owner11
Badr Nhairy
John DOE
app team
Neha Srivastava

Comment: Also I have added a picture to my question of the csv

Comment: Edit the question and put the sample data. Avoid in chats